# ConfigParser read Booleans / String / Integer at the same time with Python

Tags: python, list, configparser

Here is my **config.ini**:

```
[LOADER]
text = example text
size = 17
settings = None
run = False
```

But when I print it, using:

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
print(config._sections['LOADER'])
```

I get this:

```
{'text': 'example text', 'size': '17', 'settings': 'None', 'run': 'False'}
```

But I want this:

```
{'text': 'example text', 'size': 17, 'settings': None, 'run': False}
```

I tried several methods with ConfigParser, I tried to edit the list to replace the strings in boolean, but I really can't do it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive function could be good for this:

```py
def load_it(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: load_it(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [load_it(elem) for elem in obj]
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        if obj == 'None':
            return None
        if obj.isnumeric():
            return int(obj)
        if obj.replace('.', '', 1).isnumeric():
            return float(obj)
        if obj.upper() in ('TRUE', 'FALSE', 'T', 'F'):
            return obj.upper() in ('TRUE', 'T')

    return obj


data = load_it({'text': 'example text', 'size': '17', 'settings': 'None', 'run': 'False'})
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'text': 'example text', 'size': 17, 'settings': None, 'run': False}
```

Comment: works perfectly thank you very much, too bad there is no option with ConfigParser, but it works that's the main thing!

Comment: No problem! Although not required, also consider accepting the answer if it helped you out.

Comment: The list and dict parsing methods are incorrect in the above code.